# Word Addin: How to find a heading and insert text there?

Tags: office365, office-js, word-addins

How to list headings (Heading 1, Heading 2, etc.), find a particular (by name) one and insert a paragraph there? Is it doable in new Word JS API?

**Update**. Thank you Rick! Pasting here code **which does the trick**:

```
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        try {
            let paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
            context.load(paragraphs, ['items']);

            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands
            await context.sync();

            let listItems: HeroListItem[] = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; ++i) {
                let item = paragraphs.items[i];

                context.load(item, ['text', 'style', 'styleBuiltIn']);

                // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands
                await context.sync();

                if (item.style === 'Heading 1' || item.style === 'Heading 2') {
                    listItems.push({
                        primaryText: item.text + ' (' + item.style + ')'
                    });

                    if (item.text === 'Late days') {
                        let newLineItem = item.getNextOrNullObject();
                        context.load(item, ['text', 'style', 'styleBuiltIn']);
                        newLineItem.insertParagraph('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<My inserted text>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', 'After');
                    }
                }
            }

            this.setState({listItems: listItems});
        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({listItems: [{primaryText: 'error:' + error}]});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when you say "name" you mean the text of the heading. 
This can be done. Your code should load all the paragraphs. Iterate through them and use the **style** or **styleBuiltIn** property to find the ones with style names beginning with "Heading". Then iterate through those looking at the **text** property to find the one you want. Then use the `insertParagraph` method to insert the new paragraph.

UPDATE: (Responding to the OP's question below): You should always minimize calls of `context.sync`, so you should try to avoid calling it in a loop. Try using the for loop to add each paragraph to an array and then `context.load` the array and do `context.sync`. Then loop through the array and do your style and text check. BTW, in the code you added to your question, your 3rd call of `context.load` is unnecessary. You can also delete your second call of `context.load`, provided that you rewrite the first call of `context.load` as:

```
context.load(paragraphs, ['text', 'style']);
```

Also, your code doesn't use `styleBuiltIn`, so you can remove all references to it.

Comment: Thank you Rick! Off-topic question - should I do context.sync() for every element in array one by one or should I load all needed elements first and then do context.sync once?